# what is the better way to manage the routes in sails and angular?

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

Im pretty confuse with routing actions and views in my sails project.
What is the better practice to do that? For example, I created a PageController.js to manage views. How can I integreate it with Angular routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to **AngularJS** There is no a *better* way than other. There are just different ways. You can take a look into these two commonly wide used routing system in AngularJS

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router